# Mix Project Without a lib path

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, hex-pm

I have an existing ruby project that contains a list of protocol-buffer definitions. I would like to setup a `mix.exs` file and generate a `hex` package based on those same protocol-buffer definitions.

I can't seem to find out how to configure my mix project to use something other than the `./lib` directory for containing my `.ex` files. That directory is already use by the ruby project for packaging the ruby gem so I would like to use a `./elixir_lib` directory when I'm packaging this project.

Anyone know how to change the `mix.exs` file to tell it to use something other than `./lib`?

Answer (score 1):

Found it by digging through the elixir source code. In the `project/0` function of your `mix.exs` file you can just set `elixirc_paths: ["./elixir_lib"]`. The default value is `["lib"]`, but I've moved it to use `["./elixir_lib"]` in my project.